# Check members attribute using for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

In my app each project is link to a team that has several and each member need to answer a survey that is store in my data base inside "Response"

I would like to show a jumbotron in my page only if all users have a Response in the data base.

I tried :

```
<div class="container paddingtop80 marginbottom30">
{% for member in project.team_id.members.all %}
    {% if member.response_set.count > 0 %}
  <div class="jumbotron greenback">
    <h4>Welcome to the Project test "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
  </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      <h4>Welcome to the Project "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
    </div>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
<div class="container paddingtop80 marginbottom30">
{% for member in project.team_id.members.all %}
    {% if member.response_set.count > 0 %}
  <div class="jumbotron greenback">
    <h4>Welcome to the Project test "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
  </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="jumbotron greenback">
      <h4>Welcome to the Project "{{  project.name }}" Detail page</h4>
    </div>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
 </div>
```

the problem is that like you can see now my jumbotron is printed 3 times since I have 3 members.

How can I check for the 3 members if the Response existe or is >0 and to print only once the jumbotron ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a method on the Project to check if there are responses for any of the members. Something like:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    def has_member_responses(self):
        return Response.objects.filter(member__team__project=self).exists()
```

Now in your template you can remove the for loop and simply do:

```
{% if project.has_member_responses %}
```

Comment: Thx you very much Daniel !